# ASP.NET command line problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-server-2008

I want to execute some ms dos commands from our asp.net code (command line arguements). But system is not permitting this (Windows 2008 server). Any help would be great. The same code is working fine on our Windows 2003 server. See the code I use below.

```
protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo =

    new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    if (process != null)
    {
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");
        process.StandardInput.WriteLine("md test123");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you define *"system is not permitting this"*?

Comment: This is a bit of a security risk, you would need to give the Application Pool user, permissions to the executable directory. You're better off dropping a batch file somewhere in the web application directory, and then giving AppPool permissions to execute it.

Comment: If dir and md <newdir> is everything you do, why don't you use the System.IO namespace? I would go that way as long as possible, only using a different approach when the functionality is not available using a programmatic usable way.

Answer (score 1):

Try using impersonation to execute that code. Here is a class I created for instance-based programmatic impersonation:

```
/// <summary> 
/// Leverages the Windows API (advapi32.dll) to programmatically impersonate a user. 
/// </summary> 
public class ImpersonationContext : IDisposable 
{ 
    #region constants 

    private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2; 
    private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0; 

    #endregion 

    #region global variables 

    private WindowsImpersonationContext impersonationContext; 
    private bool impersonating; 

    #endregion 

    #region unmanaged code 

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll")] 
    private static extern int LogonUserA(String lpszUserName, String lpszDomain, String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken); 

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
    private static extern int DuplicateToken(IntPtr hToken, int impersonationLevel, ref IntPtr hNewToken); 

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] 
    private static extern bool RevertToSelf(); 

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] 
    private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle); 

    #endregion 

    #region constructors 

    public ImpersonationContext() 
    { 
        impersonating = false; 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Overloaded constructor and begins impersonating. 
    /// </summary> 
    public ImpersonationContext(string userName, string password, string domain) 
    { 
        this.BeginImpersonationContext(userName, password, domain); 
    } 

    #endregion 

    #region impersonation methods 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Begins the impersonation context for the specified user. 
    /// </summary> 
    /// <remarks>Don't call this method if you used the overloaded constructor.</remarks> 
    public void BeginImpersonationContext(string userName, string password, string domain) 
    { 
        //initialize token and duplicate variables 
        IntPtr token = IntPtr.Zero; 
        IntPtr tokenDuplicate = IntPtr.Zero; 

        if (RevertToSelf()) 
        { 
            if (LogonUserA(userName, domain, password, LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref token) != 0) 
            { 
                if (DuplicateToken(token, 2, ref tokenDuplicate) != 0) 
                { 
                    using (WindowsIdentity tempWindowsIdentity = new WindowsIdentity(tokenDuplicate)) 
                    { 
                        //begin the impersonation context and mark impersonating true 
                        impersonationContext = tempWindowsIdentity.Impersonate(); 
                        impersonating = true; 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        //close the handle to the account token 
        if (token != IntPtr.Zero) 
            CloseHandle(token); 

        //close the handle to the duplicated account token 
        if (tokenDuplicate != IntPtr.Zero) 
            CloseHandle(tokenDuplicate); 
    } 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Ends the current impersonation context. 
    /// </summary> 
    public void EndImpersonationContext() 
    { 
        //if the context exists undo it and dispose of the object 
        if (impersonationContext != null) 
        { 
            //end the impersonation context and dispose of the object 
            impersonationContext.Undo(); 
            impersonationContext.Dispose(); 
        } 

        //mark the impersonation flag false 
        impersonating = false; 
    } 

    #endregion 

    #region properties 

    /// <summary> 
    /// Gets a value indicating whether the impersonation is currently active. 
    /// </summary> 
    public bool Impersonating 
    { 
        get 
        { 
            return impersonating; 
        } 
    } 

    #endregion 

    #region IDisposable implementation 

    ~ImpersonationContext() 
    { 
        Dispose(false); 
    } 

    public void Dispose() 
    { 
        Dispose(true);                
    } 

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    { 
        if (disposing) 
        { 
            if (impersonationContext != null) 
            { 
                impersonationContext.Undo(); 
                impersonationContext.Dispose(); 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    #endregion     
}
```

Here is an example of how to implement it:

```
using (ImpersonationContext context = new ImpersonationContext("user", "password", "domain")) 
{ 
    if (context.Impersonating) 
    { 
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo =  new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");   
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;   
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;   
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;   

        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);      
        if (process != null)   
        {   
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("dir");   
            process.StandardInput.WriteLine("md test123");   
        }  
    } 
}
```