# Attempting to call command prompt execuable in a C# / ASP.NET / IIS 7.5 / Win7 Environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, shell, iis-7.5

On the server, I'm attempting to open the command prompt and call an executable which converts a file to PDF. For this I am using the PDFCreator open source program.

In C# I am calling with this code:

```
    ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"cd c:\program files (x86)\pdfcreator");
    process.StandardInput.WriteLine(@"PDFCreator.exe /PF""c:\dwf\dwf.dwf""");
```

It runs with no error, yet yields no result. What this PDFCreator.exe does is call another program, Autodesk Design Review which opens, uses the PDF driver to print to PDF, and saves the file. The command you see works fine being running standalone by me.

From scouring other threads it seems security could be my issue. So I have gone to the PDFCreator and Design Review folders/executables and granted full access to NETWORK, NETWORK SERVICE, IIS_WPG, IIS_IUSRS, and ASP.NET Machine account (realize this is probably a security thread but will disable once i figure out source of the issue). This has not helped.

It should be noted than i can change directory using the first command above, and then create a "test123" folder in both PDFCreator and Design Review folders. Seems I am getting close here, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried supplying your arguments via ProcessStartInfo.Arguments?

Comment: Tried this with and without the cmd.exe but same result. aspx pages runs with no result or error message.   ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        processStartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PDFCreator\\PDFCreator.exe";
        processStartInfo.Arguments = @"/PF""C:\dwf\dwf.dwf"" /NoStart";
        Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

Comment: A technique I've used in the past is to call the exe from a .bat file which pipes the output of the command to a log file. See if there are any hidden error messages, don't assume its reporting back correctly.

Comment: @SteveCalPoly Try `ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"); processStartInfo.Arguments = "/c C:\\Program Files(X86)\\PDFCreator\\PDFCreator.exe /PF \"C:\\dwf\\dwf.dwf\" /NoStart";`  CMD /c executes whatever command you specify and then exits.

Comment: Is your Application Pool running under Full Trust?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using cmd.exe instead of running PDFCreator.exe directly?

Comment: Also, try setting RedirectStandardError to true as well - errors tend to get sent to their own stream, rather than StandardOutput

Comment: codeulike7: tried that am not getting any output using:            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            Response.Write(result);

Comment: I will try running the app directly instead of through cmd next, no idea i could do that

Comment: I have this same problem. I've gone down numerous impersonation routes. One of which seems to work properly by using the code found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444572/asp-net-command-line-problem. I got this working locally by: 1. Creating An Admin user (add them to Admin group) 'pdfmaker'
2. Give access to a specific folder where I may write the pdf to. I also give appropriate permissions for my 'pdfmaker' to execute the pdf command line app. 3. Creating an impersonationContext using the code mentioned above
4. It successfully logs in using the Win32 API, and impersonates this a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the issue over at serverfault. The app I was calling needs to open another app on the desktop and then print to PDF. IIS cannot open programs on the desktop unless set in the `services --> service name --> log` on tab.

Unfortunately, the app I am calling isn't in the services panel so I'm currently stuck again, but at least I know it's not a C# problem.

Comment: A link to the serverfault mentioned would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

SteveCalPoly and Val Akkapeddi comments are very interesting.
Anyway, I use the following methods to run executable with command prompt

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes a shell command synchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">string command</param>
    /// <returns>string, as output of the command.</returns>
    public void ExecuteCommandSync(object command)
    {
        try
        {
            // create the ProcessStartInfo using "cmd" as the program to be run,
            // and "/c " as the parameters.
            // Incidentally, /c tells cmd that we want it to execute the command that follows,
            // and then exit.
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo =
                new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);

            // The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
            // This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            // Do not create the black window.
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            // Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
            proc.Start();
            // Get the output into a string
            string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            // Display the command output.
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            // Log the exception
        }
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Execute the command Asynchronously.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="command">string command.</param>
    public void ExecuteCommandAsync(string command)
    {
        try
        {
            //Asynchronously start the Thread to process the Execute command request.
            Thread objThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ExecuteCommandSync));
            //Make the thread as background thread.
            objThread.IsBackground = true;
            //Set the Priority of the thread.
            objThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
            //Start the thread.
            objThread.Start(command);
        }
        catch (ThreadStartException objException)
        {
            // Log the exception
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException objException)
        {
            // Log the exception
        }
        catch (Exception objException)
        {
            // Log the exception
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gave this a shot and had the same result as my block of code. I'm almost certain that it is a permission issue but am not sure which logging to check to track it down. The event viewer definitely has nothing, and once again the command runs successfully when i paste it into the command prompt myself. Is there an IIS 7.5 account missing from my list above that was not given permission to the two executables in this program?

Comment: @SteveCalPoly Look at IIS Configuration; in the Advanced Settings of the application pool configured in your application there is the name of the user account that is used (NETWORKSERVICE in my case).

Comment: I created an application pool named "MyAppPool" that uses the default ApplicationPoolIdentity Identity. According to this article, http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/624/application-pool-identities/ you set permissions on the program executables like IIS AppPool\MyAppPool. I have done this where necessary and no result.

Comment: I can actually see the PDFCreator.exe process in the task manager running and assigned to "MyAppPool." This seems good, only it does not seem to want to run the program as it runs from the command line.

Comment: @SteveCalPoly so you mean it's solved? If you think it's a permission trobule can you put your ProcessStartInfo  code in a Console Application and run as an administrator? Does it work?

Comment: Not solved, process is in the task manager but the application never runs and completes its program. At this point I'm just trying to call firefox.exe, and even it won't run. Just creates a process in task manager but no window opens. Is there a way to test this removing ALL security?  Process mapQuickbooksDrive = new Process();
        mapQuickbooksDrive.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        mapQuickbooksDrive.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\test.bat";
        mapQuickbooksDrive.Start();

Answer (score 0):

The System.Diagnostics.Process class has a method called WaitForExit() which will wait for its launched process to exit before continuing and then will return its return code.

Try creating a batch file with your commands and then running the batch file via the Process class. What happens if you use Process.WaitForExit(); after you call Process.Start(processInfo); ? Is there a return code from process.WaitForExit() at all?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the errors are going to the StandardError stream and so you never see them?

Also, why not call PDFCreator.exe directly instead of via cmd.exe?

Try something like this

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\program files (x86)\pdfcreator");
processStartInfo.Arguments = @"/PF""c:\dwf\dwf.dwf"""
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
processStartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

// Read the output stream first and then wait.
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
string errors = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Process.Start(@"c:\program files (x86)\pdfcreator\pdfcreator.exe",@"/PF""c:\dwf\dwf.dwf"" /NoStart"), all this does is start a process in the task manager but the application never actually opens and completes its task. I tried your code too, the aspx page loads indefinitely and never produces anything from strings output or errors. I went ahead and posted a question over at serverfault maybe they know of some security issue i am missing. I did a quick test trying to call Firefox.exe, making sure to grand MyApplicationPool access and even that won't open.